# How to grab substring in groovy?

Tags: groovy

May I know how to extract the substring "10111" from string "some infor [1:5] 10111" in groovy?
The following code written by me, are there any better way to do this?

```
parentString = "some infor [1:5] 10111"
String childString = parentString
println childString.substring(16)
```

Comment: are you always expecting `10111` to be at index 16 and the last part of the string? if so that works just fine. But if `10111` could appear elsewhere or be a different length then you need to explain those other conditions and how you want to choose what to substring.

Comment: Yes, '10111' is the last part of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
def parentString = "some infor [1:5] 10111"
def childString  = parentString.replaceAll( /.*\[\d+:\d+]\s*(.*)/ , '$1' )
println childString
```

about regex: https://regex101.com/r/MWVdGX/1